# Serverless (not so) fun with azure-function-express & express4-tedious

Tags: node.js, azure, express, serverless, tedious

Please help! I can get this code working on a node.js express server ok. I did have a router file on the Express app. However, my understanding is that the routing is done in the function.json file so there is no need to use it anymore.

For some reason, I can't get a response when I try to put it in a serverless Azure function... I've tried using the router file again, I've tried using app.get(... for the query but they done work either.

My index.js file is:

```
const createHandler = require("azure-function-express").createHandler;
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const tediousExpress = require('express4-tedious');

const app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.sql = tediousExpress({
        "server"  : process.env.sqlServer,
        "userName": process.env.sqlUserName,
        "password": process.env.sqlPassword,
        "options": { 
            "encrypt": true, 
            "database": process.env.sqlDatabase 
        }
    });
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.text()); 

app.use(function (req, res) {
    req.sql("select * from todo for json path")
        .into(res, '[]');
});

module.exports = createHandler(app);
```

My function.json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "todo",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```